# (wpf) itemscontrol moving animation in canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list, like:

```cs
class MyBox
{
    public int X{set;get;} //X binding ok ,this just example
    //...
}
List<MyBox> boxes{set;get;}
```

and i create Button with the list, like :

```xml
        <Style x:Key="boxTemplate" TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

there the use:

```xml
<itemscontrol itemsSource="{Binding boxes}" Style="{StaticReSource boxTemplate}" />
```

the question is:
**How can i create a moving animation when MyBox.X changed?**
Thanks!
Edit:
i try to use renderTransform.TranslateTransform, this work, but move distance is wrong!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i fixed myself.
i create a MoveX value which used to calc moving animation from and to:

```cs
class MyBox
{
    int X {set;get;} //bind to xmal
    int MoveX{set;get;} //not bind,used to move
}
```

then, after moving action(in which MoveX is changed, moving animation from=old MoveX, to=new Movex), i set `MyBox.X = 0`,and , i don't no why, moving animation works well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).